# TinyMCE editor not working properly

Tags: tinymce

I am using tinymce editor but it is not saving data properly that is when i enter details for description and short-description for product details and click on save it shows validation error. 
And when i enter details for meta description it clears out the data.

Help me out to solve this issue. Any Solution for this??

Comment: you may get help from here : http://alanstorm.com/magento_html5_tinymce

Comment: Still it is not working. shows validation error